# How to check if the value already exists in android sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have application where user enters name and other details for specific date. I need to check whether value/name user is trying to add exists already in the database column **name**. I have this code but this doesn't work as it selects only one value.  Thanks

```
Cursor c = dbe.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM tbl_user WHERE meeting_date LIKE'" + mydate + "'", null);

if ((c.getString(3)).equals(editTextName.getText().toString()))

{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only checking for existence of a value in a field,  the easiest way is to do a select count with the appropriate filter.

Something along the lines of

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tbl_user
WHERE meeting_date LIKE ' + my_date'
AND name = ' + editTextName.getText() + '
```

this would allow you to easily and quickly determine if those value exist in your table.

If you need to check multiple tables, then you would have to do a join between those tables and write your filter accordingly.

If by chance you don't have a good handle on SQL.
This site is a good starting place:
[W3Schools SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I use check if (c!=null) 
c is always different than null

Answer (score 1):

You are only selecting one column (`name`) and yet in your `if` you are trying to compare the contents of a (non-existent) third column (Not sure why you're trying to do that, but it's a problem, obviously).

Rather than trying to do it that way, why not use the column title?

So your `if` would look like this (and it doesn't matter what position the column is in your cursor):

```
if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")).equals(editTextName.getText().toString()))
```

Comment: What does the logcat say when it crashes?

Comment: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
 E/AndroidRuntime(4433): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(4433): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table tbl_user already exists: , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tbl_user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,surname TEXT,meeting_title TEXT,meeting_date DATE);